# Determine user that stopped or started service in .NET windows service

Tags: .net, windows, service

Is it possible, without reading from the security event logs, to determine what user requested a service be stopped from within the .NET based windows service that is being stopped?

Comment: Log what? I'm trying to determine the user that requested to stop "my" service.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question to mean one service was stopping another.  In the service's Stop event, do you see the current user being the one configured at the run-as user, or the actual user initiating the action?

Comment: It will be the user context of that user which is running the service, not the one that is requesting the stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You will have to parse the security events logs to get this information.